# How to get google reviews from deal name

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api

I'd like to know how could I get number of google reviews and total rating.

What kinda api should I use?

For instance I'd like to get count of google reviews of 'Karl Strauss Brewing Company', or "Seaview Restaurant".

How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this, at least not with the free version of the Google Places API.

The API allows you to view up to 5 reviews for a place. **There is currently no way to get all reviews or the total review count**:

> **`reviews[]`** a JSON array of up to five reviews.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults)

Whether or not the paid version of the API offers better access to the reviews, I don't know.